# TinkerPop Gremlin, how get child elements filtered and grouped

Tags: gremlin, tinkerpop3

I'm new to using Gremlin and I need help to set the best query to select unique and filtered results.

Starting from a `team` I would get `player` (**note**: each player can play for more than one team) of each `team` connected by `is_friends_with`

**The result** *(I would like to get)*

```
[
 {
   "Player": "Icardi",
   "Teams": ["Valladolid"]
 },
 {
   "Player": "Kroll",
   "Teams": ["Valladolid"]
 },

  {
   "Player": "Baggio",
   "Teams": ["Eagles"]
 },

 {
   "Player": "Papin",
   "Teams": ["Valladolid","Eagls"]
 },
]
```

**The graph**

[image]

**The schema**:

```
 g.addV('team').as('1').
 property(single, 'name', 'Eagles').
 addV('player').as('2').
 property(single, 'name', 'Zico').addV('team').
 as('3').
 property(single, 'name', 'team A').
 addV('team').as('4').
 property(single, 'name', 'Horses').
 addV('player').as('5').
 property(single, 'name', 'Papin').
 addV('player').as('6').
 property(single, 'name', 'Ronaldo').
 addV('player').as('7').
 property(single, 'name', 'Visco').
 addV('player').as('8').
 property(single, 'name', 'Baggio').
 addV('tournament').as('9').
 addV('team').as('10').
 property(single, 'name', 'Valladolid').
 addV('player').as('11').
 property(single, 'name', 'Kroll').
 addV('player').as('12').
 property(single, 'name', 'Icardi').
 addE('owned').from('1').to('5').addE('owned').
 from('1').to('6').addE('owned').from('1').
 to('8').addE('owned').from('3').to('6').
 addE('owned').from('3').to('7').
 addE('created').from('3').to('9').
 addE('is_friends_with').from('3').to('10').
 addE('is_friends_with').from('3').to('1').
 addE('owned').from('4').to('8').addE('owned').
 from('4').to('2').addE('owned').from('4').
 to('5').addE('owned').from('4').to('7').
 addE('invited').from('9').to('1').
 addE('invited').from('9').to('4').
 addE('owned').from('10').to('11').
 addE('owned').from('10').to('12').
 addE('owned').from('10').to('5')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it using `group`

```java
gremlin>  g.V().
......1>    has('name','team A').
......2>    out('is_friends_with').as('a').
......3>    out('owned').
......4>    group().
......5>      by('name').
......6>      by(select('a').values('name').fold()).
......7>    unfold()

==>Papin=[Valladolid, Eagles]
==>Icardi=[Valladolid]
==>Baggio=[Eagles]
==>Ronaldo=[Eagles]
==>Kroll=[Valladolid]
```

To get the exact format that matches your JSON, we can just add a`project` step to the query.

```java
gremlin>  g.V().
......1>    has('name','team A').
......2>    out('is_friends_with').as('a').
......3>    out('owned').
......4>    group().
......5>      by('name').
......6>      by(select('a').values('name').fold()).
......7>    unfold().
......8>    project('player','teams').
......9>      by(keys).
.....10>      by(values)

==>[player:Papin,teams:[Valladolid,Eagles]]
==>[player:Icardi,teams:[Valladolid]]
==>[player:Baggio,teams:[Eagles]]
==>[player:Ronaldo,teams:[Eagles]]
==>[player:Kroll,teams:[Valladolid]]
```

Comment: Thanks! It is similar to my own solution, but it works! Very interesting and... light! I really appreciated your help!

Answer (score 1):

gremlin> g.V().has("name", "team A").sideEffect(__.out("owned").hasLabel("player").aggregate("my_player").limit(1)).both("is_friends_with").hasLabel("team").as("team2").out("owned").hasLabel("player").as("friends_player").where(without("my_player")).as("friends_player2").select("team2", "friends_player2").group().by(select("friends_player2")).by(select("team2").fold()).unfold().project("Player", "Teams").by(select(keys).values("name")).by(select(values).unfold().values("name").fold())

```
==>[Player:Baggio,Teams:[Eagles]]
==>[Player:Kroll,Teams:[Valladolid]]
==>[Player:Icardi,Teams:[Valladolid]]
==>[Player:Papin,Teams:[Valladolid,Eagles]]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).